# how to move elements to the top in an object array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array as:

```
var user = [{name: 'name1', isActive: false}, {name: 'name2', isActive: false}, {name: 'name3', isActive: true}, {name: 'name4', isActive: false}, {name: 'name9', isActive: true}, {name: 'name8', isActive: false}];
```

What I want to do is, sort the array so that, user with isActive is as true, all are pushed to the top. I tried following but it didnt work.

```
user.sort(function(a,b){
    a.isActive ? 1 : b.isActive ? -1 : 0
});
```

Answer (score 1):

this is shorter

```
user.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.isActive - a.isActive
})
```

arithmetic operation on boolean coerces boolean to integer (1 for true and 0 for false) and if comparision function returns negative, a precedes b. If a is true and b is false, a will be placed before b. If b is true and a is false, b is placed before a.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var user = [{name: 'name1', isActive: false}, {name: 'name2', isActive: false}, {name: 'name3', isActive: true}, {name: 'name4', isActive: false}, {name: 'name9', isActive: true}, {name: 'name8', isActive: false}];

user.sort(function(a, b){return b.isActive - a.isActive;});
console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution as :

```
user.sort(function(a,b){
   if (!b.isActive) {
        return -1;
    } else if (b.isActive) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Your sort function must be antisymmetric and transitive. In particular, if `a` and `b` are both active or both inactive, you need to return 0.

Comment: Thanks!, the problem now is that sometimes the object wont have isActive property , how can this be tackled ?

Comment: check the existence in starting, if the property does not exist return 0.

Comment: @ren No, don't return zero. This would violate transitivity. (true < false, but missing = false and missing = true.) You need to decide whether items where the property is missing go to the front or to the back.

Comment: @RaymondChen : yes i agree.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
var user = [{name: 'name1', isActive: false}, {name: 'name2', isActive: false}, {name: 'name3', isActive: true}, {name: 'name4', isActive: false}, {name: 'name9', isActive: true}, {name: 'name8', isActive: false}];

user.sort(function(x, y) {
  return (x.isActive === y.isActive)? 0 : x.isActive? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use it, Thanks

```
var user = [
{
    name: 'name1', isActive: false
}, 
{
    name: 'name2', isActive: false
}, 
{
    name: 'name3', isActive: true
},
{
    name: 'name4', isActive: false
},
{
    name: 'name9', isActive: true
},
{
    name: 'name8', isActive: false
}
];
let sortedUser = user.sort(function(a,b){
   if (!b.isActive) {
        return -1;
    } else if (b.isActive) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
});
console.log("Sorted", sortedUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't like use `-` between two boolean, my solution would be like this, also it work well with absence of isActive property.

```
var users = [{name: 'name1', isActive: false}, {name: 'name2', isActive: false}, {name: 'name3', isActive: true}, {name: 'name4', isActive: false}, {name: 'name8', isActive: true}, {name: 'name9', isActive: false}, {name: 'name10'}];

users.sort(function(l, u) {
    var lv = l.isActive ? 1 : 2, uv = u.isActive ? 1 : 2;
    return lv - uv;
});

console.log(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution to you problem is:
    user.sort((a,b) => b.isActive)

Here, if the object won't have isActive property it'll assume the property is false by default. Hope this helps :)